# std::enable_if With Non-Type Template Parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enable-if, non-type-template-parameter

how would you go about using non-type template parameter comparison in a `std::enable_if`?
I can not figure out how to do this again. (I once had this working, but I lost the code so I can't look back on it, and I can't find the post I found the answer in either.)

```
template<int Width, int Height, typename T>
class Matrix{
    static
    typename std::enable_if<Width == Height, Matrix<Width, Height, T>>::type
    Identity(){
        Matrix ret;
        for (int y = 0; y < Width; y++){
            elements[y][y] = T(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Fixed missing bracket as pointed out in comments.

Comment: I'd probably use a `static_assert` for that. It provides clear error messages.

Comment: `static_assert` is indeed the right tool: `std::enable_if` is for SFINAE, and there's no SFINAE possible for a non-template member of a class template.

Comment: I have thought of using `static_assert`, ultimately I may end up using it. But I did have this working before, and with the advantage of auto complete not even listing the function for non-square matrices in the first place. Largely at this point though, is trying to figure out how I once had this done with strictly `std::enable_if`.

Comment: There is a `>` missing at the end of the `enable_if` line. Actually (after this correction) your code works, however it is is not different that a `static_assert` (it gives a compilation error when calling `Identity` for non-square matrix type.) It is just more obscure than a `static_assert`.

Comment: @alfC, even after this correction, the OP's code doesn't work, since `Identity` function should be template. Just try to instantiate `Matrix<1, 2, int>`. And this is differs from `static_assert` behavior.

Comment: @alfC: I got bitten just like you. Even after that correction, a non-square matrix can't be instantiated at all.

Comment: @syam, you are right! I am posting an answer that may be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on what kind of error/failure you want to raise on invalid code. Here it is one possibility (leaving aside the obvious `static_assert(Width==Height, "not square matrix");`)

(C++98 style)

```
#include<type_traits>
template<int Width, int Height, typename T>
class Matrix{
public:
    template<int WDummy = Width, int HDummy = Height>
    static typename std::enable_if<WDummy == HDummy, Matrix>::type
    Identity(){
        Matrix ret;
        for (int y = 0; y < Width; y++){
        // elements[y][y] = T(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};

int main(){
    Matrix<5,5,double> m55;
    Matrix<4,5,double> m45; // ok
    Matrix<5,5, double> id55 = Matrix<5,5, double>::Identity(); // ok
//  Matrix<4,5, double> id45 = Matrix<4,5, double>::Identity(); // compilation error! 
//     and nice error: "no matching function for call to ‘Matrix<4, 5, double>::Identity()"
}
```

---

**EDIT:** In C++11 the code can be more compact and clear, (it works in `clang 3.2` but not in `gcc 4.7.1`, so I am not sure how standard it is):

(C++11 style)

```
template<int Width, int Height, typename T>
class Matrix{
public:
    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<Width == Height>::type>
    static Matrix
    Identity(){
        Matrix ret;
        for(int y = 0; y < Width; y++){
            // ret.elements[y][y] = T(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

---

**EDIT 2020:** (C++14)

```
template<int Width, int Height, typename T>
class Matrix{
public:
    template<typename = std::enable_if_t<Width == Height>>
    static Matrix
    Identity()
    {
        Matrix ret;
        for(int y = 0; y < Width; y++){
        //  ret.elements[y][y] = T(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

---

(C++20) https://godbolt.org/z/cs1MWj

```
template<int Width, int Height, typename T>
class Matrix{
public:
    static Matrix
    Identity()
        requires(Width == Height)
    {
        Matrix ret;
        for(int y = 0; y < Width; y++){
        //  ret.elements[y][y] = T(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Comment: Just beat me to finishing up my own answer on the question. Thanks for the answer regardless. Marked as accepted.

Comment: In c++11 there is a more compact alternative: ` template<int WDummy = Width, class Dummy = typename std::enable_if<WDummy == Height, Matrix>::type> static Matrix Identity(){...} `

Comment: Is `WDummy` even needed? MSVC: CTP Nov '12 with /W4 compiles just fine without it.

Comment: @LostOfThought, do you mean in the original answer? You can get away with `template<int HDummy = Height>
    static typename std::enable_if<Width == HDummy, Matrix<Width, Height, T> >::type Identity(){...}`. In the comment I still need to have `WDummy`, but I can do get rid of `Dummy`: `template<int WDummy = Width, class = typename std::enable_if<WDummy == Height, Matrix>::type> static Matrix Identity(){...}`

Comment: I thought that in C++98, function templates could not have default parameters.

Comment: I think the second option only works in C++11. The first option can be adapted to work in C++98 (e.g. by using `boost::enable_if_c`)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question here: [Using C++11 std::enable_if to enable...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786479/using-c11-stdenable-if-to-enable-member-function-if-vector-is-specific-lengt/13786594#13786594)

In my solution, SFINAE occurs within my templated return type, therefore making the function template in itself valid. In the course of this, the function itself also becomes templated.

```
template<int Width, int Height, typename T>
class Matrix{
    template<typename EnabledType = T>
        static
        typename Matrix<Width, Height,
            typename std::enable_if<Width == Height, EnabledType>::type>
        Identity(){
        Matrix ret;
        for (int y = 0; y < Width; y++){
            ret.elements[y][y] = T(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a more compact version in my answer, but it doesn't work in `gcc`. BTW, the `typename` before `Matrix` is at best redundant.

Comment: The code in your Edit is the same as in my new answer, there is no point in repeating it here.

Comment: I see that now. Wasn't intended. I've been messing with this code all night, I really am that bored. Regardless, thank you for your help.

Comment: Anyways, are you really implementing a matrix class?, not to disanimate you but did you take a look at uBlas and Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page (this one even has static array sizes like the one you are designing), but is cool to reimplement, I am sure it doesn't have a cool `Identity` static function.

Comment: Well, a few buddies of mine had this idea of making a game, one is currently in college, mainly taking asm classes right now, and I came from AS3 where there's a lot of hand-holding. Both of us seem to be doing things the hardest way possible. I'm writing everything from scratch, even my own OpenGL loaders, and it's been a uphill struggle for me this entire time, especially reading the 'proper' way to do things in C++11, and having things robust enough for any future things I want to make. (Let alone everything being cross-platform as well, going only off of the system APIs andOpenGL)tl;dr:Yes

Comment: On the plus side, all I really have left now is strictly the Matrix/Matrix math functions, most else is already done including projections, the like. (Yes, backwards, I know.)