# Enable function only for some template specification if template is of integer type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a Vector class which has a template of `<unsigned int Dim>`, eg. I can do `Vector<2>` for a vector in 2-dimensional space, `Vector<4>` for 4-dimensional, etc. I want to add some methods to the class if `Dim == specific value`, for instance `CrossProduct` for `Vector<3>`, or `x,y,z,w` getters for a vector of sufficient dimension. If used with a Vector of incorrect dimensions, I would hope to get a compile error.

I have looked around quite a lot, one of the things that I believe are close enough is `std::enable_if`, however, I have no clue how to use it for my particular case (where the condition is either `Dim == x`, or `Dim > x`).

Is this the right way, or is there a completely different way I should do this?

I am using C++17, by the way.

Comment: Would be simpler in C++20 with `requires`.

Comment: What happens if you just use `std::enable_if_t<Dim == 3, double>` as your return type instead of `double`? Then if Dim isn't 3, the function has no valid return type, so the compiler can't generate it.

Comment: do you want to functions to only be available for certain values of `Dim` (SFINAE). Or do you want different implementations for values of `Dim` (template specialization)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using C++11 std::enable\_if to enable member function if vector is specific length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786479/using-c11-stdenable-if-to-enable-member-function-if-vector-is-specific-lengt)

Comment: @user253751: if `Dim` is the class template, you would have hard error. `Dim` need to be function template parameter (which might be defaulted from the class' one) for substitution failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- pre-C++20, `static_assert` might be the simplest:

  ```
  template <std::size_t Dims>
  struct Vector
  {
      // ...
      double getZ() const { static_assert(Dims >= 3);  return data[2]; }
  };
  ```
- SFINAE is possible, but complex and verbose:

  ```
  template <std::size_t Dims>
  struct Vector
  {
      // ...
      template <std::size_t D = Dims, std::enable_if_t<(D >= 3) && D == Dims, int> = 0>
      double getZ() const { return data[2]; }
  };
  ```
- Specialization is possible, but might be tricky, for example:

  ```
  struct NullVector3{};

  template <typename Derived>
  struct Vector3
  {
      // ...
      double getZ() const { return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[2]; }
  };

  template <std::size_t Dims>
  struct Vector : std::conditional_t<(Dims >= 3), Vector3<Vector<Dims>>, NullVector3> /*, ..*/
  {
      // ...
      // inherit of Vector3<Vector>::getZ() when Dims >= 3
      // inherit of no extra method from NullVector3 else.
  };
  ```
- C++20 is the simplest with `requires`:

  ```
  template <std::size_t Dims>
  struct Vector
  {
      // ...
      double getZ() const requires(Dims >= 3) { return data[2]; }
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks, switched to C++20 and requires works as expected.
However, I had issues with using static_assert() when compiling with MSVC++. Looked into it only a bit and it might be an MSVC++ problem though.

Comment: @kubci98: `static_assert` require extra C-string argument pre-C++17 -> `static_assert(Dims >= 3, "Wrong dimension");`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 you may use [Constraints and Concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

With C++17, you need to emulate them with `std::enable_if`. Alternatively you could use [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), but I would deem `enable_if` to express the intention better (automatic tools like code-completion should figure enable_if out, but most probably not a static assert).

A practical example is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13786594/21974) as found by @JHBonarius.

Comment: @JHBonarius I don't see it as a duplicate. The other question is about how to use std::enable_if, not about whether to use it or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the methods for the generic interface and add

`static_assert(Dim==3,"This method is only valid for 3-dimensional vectors.")`

as the first line in each method. This will yield much cleaner compiler error message compared to `std::enable_if` approach.

You can also use `if constexpr(Dim==x)` for the rest of the method's body  and to "specialize" the code based on the current dimension if varying implementations are needed.

Comment: @JHBonarius Of course, thank you. For some reason I cannot get used to that order.